# jquery Sticky Nav with Animation Only Works First Time

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-animate, sticky

I will do my best to explain my issue, but you can see the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xPxhf/3/

I have navigation, the bottom part of which is meant to break off and stick to the top of the user's window once a user scrolls past a certain point on the page. The way this works is that is breaks off *14px* from the top, and then animates to top: *0px*.

Then, once the user scrolls back to the top, the nav should animate back to its original position (top: *78px*). If you look at my example in jsfiddle, it does this the first time, and seems to work as expected. But if you scroll again, things go completely haywire.

Anyone have code suggestions that would make this function correctly? I've spent a couple of hours trying different fixes, but nothing has worked out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using relative values when positioning the nav. If you remove the delay and the animation and use absolute values, it works great.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xPxhf/6/

Comment: Thanks--yeah, that's how I had it before. Unfortunately, that doesn't answer my question. The animation is the integral part.

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xPxhf/7/? If so, the solution still involves moving away from relative values in addition to adjusting the top value when switching between fixed and absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this (http://jsfiddle.net/jvJc4/2/) work?